# I want instanciate a Generic type in C# unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, generic-programming, generic-list

Hello i tried to Resize a generic tab but my probleme is to initialise new element

```
    List<T> Resize<T>(List<T> list, int sz)
{
    if (list.Count < sz)
    {
        while (list.Count < sz)
        {
            T someInstance = new T(); // this line is the probleme
            list.Add(someInstance);
        }
    } else if ((list.Count > sz))
    {
        list.RemoveRange(sz, list.Count);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Thank you <3

Comment: Why not use a stack instead? Same same but different. Is your T a component? Then you'd need a Component constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the generic constraint `new()` on your definition of `T`:

```
List<T> Resize<T>(List<T> list, int sz) where T: new()
```

Of course this assumes that every type *has* a parameterless constructor.
    ...

Comment: Thank a lot for help

Comment: @valentinsorlin If this solves your issue, you can accept this answer to mark it as closed.